# Apple MusicKit Authorization errors with iOS 12 update

Tags: ios, authentication, itunes, apple-musickit

I'm using the Apple MusicKit in my app. I had the authorization setup correctly and everything was working fine for a long time. Recently since the update to iOS 12 I'm seeing these errors

```
2018-12-02 19:16:46.511567-0500 Project2[30649:3022463] [core] "Error returned from daemon: Error Domain=com.apple.accounts Code=9 "(null)""
2018-12-02 19:16:46.512835-0500 Project2[30649:3022463] SSAccountStore: Failed to fetch the backing accounts. error = Error Domain=com.apple.accounts Code=9 "(null)"
2018-12-02 19:16:46.518199-0500 Project2[30649:3022586] [core] "Error returned from daemon: Error Domain=com.apple.accounts Code=9 "(null)""
2018-12-02 19:16:46.518407-0500 Project2[30649:3022586] SSAccountStore: Failed to fetch the backing accounts. error = Error Domain=com.apple.accounts Code=9 "(null)"
2018-12-02 19:16:46.524685-0500 Project2[30649:3022586] SSAccountStore: Unable to get the local account. error = Error Domain=SSErrorDomain Code=100 "Cannot connect to iTunes Store" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot connect to iTunes Store}
```

Is anyone else facing the same issue? Is there some change that I'm supposed to make? Or redo the token? I see this asked on the apple developers forum with no response https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/105635

Comment: Same here... everything was fine but came back to the project and now it doesn't work (without changing anything). - iOS 12.1

Comment: @andres.cianio were you able to figure out the problem?

Comment: anyone figure this out yet?

Comment: IIRC simply removing the app and installing again ended up working